# Is there a way to make a method that can be called by a String?

Tags: vb.net

I need to find out if a `String` contains a specific `Substring` inside of it, then return a `Boolean` value depending on whether or not the `Substring` exists. I can create a stand-alone function that checks if a passed year exists in a passed string, like so:

Say pstrCompNum = "111-2233-44-555", and pstrCompYear = "33". This would return True, and thus, I'd know that 33 existed in this string.

```
Public Function HasYear(ByVal pstrCompNum As String, ByVal pstrCompYear As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim testString As String = pstrCompNum
        Dim testSubstring As String = testString.Substring(6, 2)
        If pstrCompYear.Equals(testSubstring) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

But what I really want is to be able to call this method using the String, for example, I might use it like this:

```
If pstrCompNum.HasYear(pstrCompYear) Then
    ''something
End If
```

This is because I plan on putting it in a loop where each iteration I check to see if a String has a year in it. Something along the lines of this:

```
Dim itHasIt As Boolean
For Each c In Name
    If c.HasYear(year) Then
        itHasIt = True
    End If
Next
```

Or something like that. I just made that up off the top of my head to help you understand.

Any recommendations for making this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, these are called [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods).

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensionMethods

    <Extension()>
    Public Function HasYear(ByVal pstrCompNum As String, ByVal pstrCompYear As String) As Boolean

        Dim testString As String = pstrCompNum
        Dim testSubstring As String = testString.Substring(6, 2)

        If pstrCompYear.Equals(testSubstring) Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return False
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks. Just a pointer for anyone else reading this, you have to put the module outside of your class, not sure if that's worth mentioning, but I'm going to anyway. Thanks @the_lotus

Comment: @BrenCou: But in this case where the pstCompNum is a composite of multiple different numbers I would not use an extension method over a string but replace the string through an object of an own class that takes the string as a constructor parameter, validates and parses it and that provides a property for each of the values.

Comment: That might be a good way to go, but unfortunately this isn't my application, I was just told to increase functionality. Its a pretty complex app and revamping how the number is stored seems like a lot of work, for (frankly) seemingly little gain. But even if it is worth it, its outside my area of responsibility where I work, I don't decide these things. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: @BrenCou personally I wouldn't do an extension. This isn't a method specific to strings but a method specific to that variable.